# How to arrange years of x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a box-plot as below in python - matplotlib, could anybody help me to reduce years' spacing in x-axis (attached picture below)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,8))

data = pd.concat([df_train.SalePrice, df_train.YearBuilt],axis=1)

sns.boxplot('YearBuilt','SalePrice',data=data)

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image: Box-plot chart]

Comment: What do you mean "reduce years' spacing"?

Comment: Yes such as 1872 - 1875 - 1880 ... like that to make x-axis more space and clear.

Answer (score 4):

Generate Some Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Generate Some Sample Data
np.random.seed(15)
dr = np.repeat(pd.date_range('1872-01-01', '2011-01-01', freq='Y').year, 10)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'YearBuilt': dr,
    'SalePrice': np.random.randint(0, 70_000, len(dr))
})
```

To set years at 5 year intervals get the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) 'YearBuilt' Columns and use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set ticks where `year % 5` is 0:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
sns.boxplot(x='YearBuilt', y='SalePrice', data=data, ax=ax)
years = np.sort(data['YearBuilt'].unique())
ax.set_xticklabels(np.where(years % 5 == 0, years, ''))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

---

Alternatively set the [`tick locator`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html#tick-locators) to a `MultipleLocator`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Generate Some Sample Data
np.random.seed(15)
dr = np.repeat(pd.date_range('1872-01-01', '2011-01-01', freq='Y').year, 10)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'YearBuilt': dr,
    'SalePrice': np.random.randint(0, 70_000, len(dr))
})
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
sns.boxplot(x='YearBuilt', y='SalePrice', data=data, ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2]